# $|\text{det}(A)| = 1$ implies $A$ is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, determinant, orthogonal-matrices, transpose

I know that $A$ orthogonal $\Rightarrow$ |det($A$)| = 1. Now I need to prove or disprove the reversed statement:

$$
|\det(A)| = 1 \Rightarrow A \,\text{ is orthogonal}
$$

This is what I'm currently trying:

$$
|\det(A)| = 1 \Rightarrow \det(A)^2 = 1 \Rightarrow \det(AA^t) = 1
$$

But I'm unsure whether this implies, that $AA^t = E_n$. Any help is welcome at this point. Maybe the statement isn't even true.

Comment: You won't  be successful .   Matrix satisfying equation $A^2=I$ has determinant which can be equal 1 but there are plenty such matrices which are not orthogonal.

Comment: Even diagonal  matrix  $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0.5 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ has determinant equal $1$.

Answer (score 16):

It's not true:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

has determinant $1$ but it's not orthogonal since the columns are not orthonormal.

Furthermore,

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you really much! I'll accept this answer as soon as possible :)

Comment: @user1551 Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 6):

No. Take any matrix $A$ with determinant $d\not=0$ and divide the elements of the first row by $d$. Then the new matrix has determinant $1$. Now it should be easy to find a counterexample to your implication.